# DataDog - pass multiple fnmatch paterns to configuration

Tags: directory, analytics, datadog, fnmatch

```
init_config:

instances:
  - directory: /mnt/ftp/generic/Salesorder
    pattern: '*_12_*.csv'
    filegauges: true
    dirtagname: history

  - directory: /mnt/ftp/generic/Salesorder
    pattern: '2021_*_*.csv'
    filegauges: true
    dirtagname: this-year
```

The directory contains multiple files with the next format YYYY_MM_SalesOrder.csv

How to use multiple patterns in a single instance?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

Only one instance per format.

This is what it is :/
Maybe in the future, there will be better options for DataDog.

```
init_config:

instances:
  - directory: /mnt/ftp/generic/Salesorder
    pattern: '*_12_*.csv'
    filegauges: true
    dirtagname: history

  - directory: /mnt/ftp/generic/Salesorder
    pattern: '2021_*_*.csv'
    filegauges: true
    dirtagname: this-year
```